# Remove n to m rows from table

Tags: jquery, pagination, tablerow, dom-manipulation

Doing a jQuery powered paginated list of view of records. the total number of records on the page can be 10,20,50,100. If 50 was selected as default and the user selects 20, then I simply want to remove the table rows beginning from 21 up to 50.

How can I do this ?

Comment: did jquery power  not give you ajax to change the default and load result based on that

Comment: well, off course you can do that. I simply do not want to make an ajax call and get the records that I already have with me

Comment: so then with out refreshing page how you will do that

Comment: eh...it explains in the question, I simply remove the rows. I have 50 rows being displayed, the user chooses 20, I remove rows 21-50. Helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using nextAll()?
Like this:

```
JSFiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLwPf/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off doing a proper refresh so that the pagination code doesn't get out of sync with what's actually displayed.

But to answer your question as asked:

```
$("#yourTableId tr").slice(20).remove();
```

That is, select all of the rows, then use the [`.slice()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to reduce the set to just the ones from row 20 (or whatever number, obviously you'd use a variable there), and then [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) them.

Note that `.slice()` uses a zero-based index, so `.slice(20)` gets you the 21st row and up. You can specify an end index, e.g., `.slice(20,50)`, but if you don't it just selects all items from the start index and up so `.slice(20)` does the job in this case.